# How to save results on multiple tables?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save an exam for each course and here is what I've tried. The error that I'm getting is error page 404 is not found and also the data is not saving in the db.

Here is my controller

```
public function exam($course_id, Request $id)
        {
            $course = Course::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
            $answers = [];
            $exam_result = 0;
            foreach ($request->get('question') as $question_id => $answer_id) {
                $question = ExamQuestion::find($question_id);
                $correct_answer = ExamOption::where('exam_questions_id', $question_id)
                    ->where('id', $answer_id)
                    ->where('is_correct', 1)->count() > 0;
                $answers[] = [
                  //this comes from the exam_results_answers
                    'exam_question_id   ' => $question_id,
                    'exam_option_id' => $answer_id,
                    'corect' => $correct_answer
                ];
                if ($correct_answer) {
                    $exam_result += $question->score;
                }
            }
            //this comes from exam result and is correct
            $exam_result = ExamResult::create([
                'exam_id' => $course->exam->id,
                'employee_id' => \Auth::id(),
                'result' => $exam_result
            ]);
            $exam_result->answers()->createMany($answers);
            return redirect()->route('learn.show', [$course->curriculum_id, $id])->with('message', 'Test score: ' . $exam_resut);
        }
```

Here is the blade

```
<form action="{{ route('exam.save', [$courses->id]) }}" method="post">
              {{ csrf_field() }}


                @foreach($courses->exam->question as $question)

                <br>{{$loop->iteration}} . {{$question->question}}</b>
                </br>

                @foreach($question->exam_options as $option)
                &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="question[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $option->id }}"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $option->text }}</br>
                @endforeach


                <br>
                @endforeach
              </br>
                 <input type="submit" value=" Submit results " />
               </form>
```

Here are the routes

```
  Route::get('/exam/{id}', 'EmployeeCoursesController@view_exam')->name('exam.show');
Route::post('/exam/{id}', 'EmployeeCoursesController@exam')->name('exam.save');
```

Comment: What is your in your route file?

Comment: If you are getting a 404, that suggests it is falling over here - `Course::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail()`. Can you check that there is a course in your database with the ID you are using?

Comment: share your route file

Comment: The db ID is correct it pulls the right view  here is the code that pulls the view. function view_exam($id)
  {
   $courses = Course::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
   return view('admin.courses.exam', compact('courses'));

  }

Comment: I get that error when I try to save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the parameters in your `exam()` function, I believe this line:

```
$course = Course::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Should actually be:

```
$course = Course::where('id', $course_id)->firstOrFail();
```

`firstOrFail()` will throw a 404 if it does not resolve a model from the database.

Comment: Thank you this got me to a different error in the foreach loop, Undefined variable: request. foreach ($request->get('question') as $question_id => $answer_id) {

Comment: after the request I get('question') which is a function on the model. Is that the correct way?

Comment: @SimonaBuga change this `Request $id` to `Request $request`

Comment: Try changing `public function exam($course_id, Request $id)` to `public function exam($course_id, Request $request)`

Comment: Amazing! we are making progress, now I have a SQL error  Unknown column 'exam_result_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `exam_results_answers` (`exam_option_id`, `exam_result_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values